# SQLite data fetch from Document directory

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have a sqlite db stored in the Document directory and images name in one of the column of table ..and Image are store in app bundle.Images are coming directly by giving the names of imgaes in the column by using code..means no need to specify any path..just name is fine.

now if i store images dynamically in the document directory and give the name of the image in image column of Sqlite db directly as above I am unable to fetch it. Do i need to specify any path to reach there..as In app bundle images are coming directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You need to specify the path to the sqlite file in the document directory.

Or use the following code with corresponding image name (Images are in document directory):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *imagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"img.png"];
yourImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imagePath]];
```

Comment: not working with the path specify with the name but when stored inthe document directly i just gave the name

Comment: @user2519391 you must store path of image stored in Document directory while u need to Fatch it. Midhun MP is right.

Comment: is there any way to download images or data in app bundle

Comment: @user2519391: No, app bundle is readonly, so you can't edit or modify it

Answer (score 0):

You can get directory path as below:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

and to get image you have to append image name after this path. You have data in your database, so from that you can get imagename.

Comment: you can use [NSString StringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",documentsDirectory,imagename];

Answer (score 0):

If the value in the database is just the name of the image (such as "someimage.png") then you have two possibilities:

1) If the image is in the app bundle then use the value from the database with the `UIImage imageNamed:` method. I believe you already have this working.

2) If the image is in the `Documents` directory then you have a little more to do. You need to obtain the full path to the `Documents` directory and then append the filename (from the database) to the path. This will give you a full path to the image in the `Documents` directory. Then to load the image you need to use the `UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:` method passing in the full file path.

Comment: thnks for full explanation :)

Comment: is there any way to download images or data in app bundle

Answer (score 0):

Use this code .

```
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory35 = [paths objectAtIndex:0];


//Essential Info
NSString *fullPathEssentialInfo = [documentsDirectory35 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"EssentialInfo.txt"];
```

This is implemented code.Thanks

Comment: In my app this string is concated so i used stringwithFormate.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example project for accessing SQLite here: https://github.com/AaronBratcher/ABSQLite